# Can Figure Out How To Get TypeScript To Be Happy with Returned Promise

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have reduced my code to this simple example that just returns a promise function. The error TypeScript 3.2 gives me is:

> Error:(1, 7) TS2739: Type '() => Promise<{}>' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<{ hasErrored: boolean; }>': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag]

The associated code is

```
const fetchUserInfoPromise1: Promise<{ hasErrored: boolean }> = () => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        resolve({ id: 1, name: 'peter' });
    });
};
export default fetchUserInfoPromise1;
```

Comment: Is the problem not literally what it says it is? You did not provide a `then` or `catch` property... https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/promise.html Please do clarify if I'm missing something.

Comment: Also you should present a [MCVE] which includes your usage of this promise.

Comment: You declare `fetchUserInfoPromise1` as a `Promise<T>`, but then assign a function to it. So type checker points you to that fact: a function cannot be assigned to a promise.

Comment: Maybe I stripped my example down too far, Let me try and bring it up a notch.

Comment: It appears you're missing the `hasErrored` property (since you didn't declare it as optional: `hasErrored?`) so what happens if you return `resolve({ id: 1, name: 'peter', hasErrored: false });`

Comment: @ErikPhilips `Type '() => Promise<{}>'`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, `fetchUserInfoPromise1` is a function that returns a `Promise`, not a `Promise` itself.

```
const fetchUserInfoPromise1 = (): Promise<{ hasErrored: boolean }> => { /* ... */ }
```

Secondly, the type parameter used in your return type definition must match the one that is being resolved. The returned `Promise` is supposed to resolve with an object `{ hasErrored: boolean }`, yet it resolves with `{ id: number, name: string }`. You need to decide what you want to accomplish.

Example:

```
const fetchUserInfoPromise1 = (): Promise<{ id: number, name: string }> => {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    resolve({ id: 1, name: 'peter' });
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks @karol-majewski I'm still strugging with TypeScript and your explanation helps a lot.  Your example shows exactly what I was trying to accomplish. I owe you one.

Comment: Anytime! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is expecting a promise, and you are returning a value. The selected answer makes sense. But there is also a very simple solution by using async if you are declaring a function like this

```
checkIfTrue(): Promise<boolean>{ return true; }
```

Then update this function as

```
async checkIfTrue(): Promise<boolean>{ return true; }
```